# SKU number from WooCommerce Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Writing a function for WooCommerce that produce a XML with information. Having problem receiving my SKU number from different item

My code to read data is something like this

```
   // Query order data 
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
   $items = $order->get_items();
   $counter = 1000;


   // Retrive Loop data 
   foreach ( $items as $item ) {
   $product_name = $item['name'];
   $product_id = $item['product_id'];
   $product_qty = $item['qty'];
   $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

   // Output Loop data
   $this->xml->writeElement('Description', $product_name); // etc..
```

The problem is when it comes to receiving the SKU number on every item. Have been trying several way to do this without success, My latest was

```
   $sku = $product->get_sku();
```

Whitin the Loop but it just throw me

```
   Call to a member function get_sku() on a non-object
```

Anyone one that have a clue how to manage to receive and write out SKU within the loop on my custom XML plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how did you declare `$product`??

try `$product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);`

before you do `$sku = $product->get_sku();`

this will make `get_sku()` available...

Comment: Thank's that was the part i was missing